# C# (Windows Forms) Input Output Keyboard and Mouse States

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, mouse

How to get keyboard and mouse input (what buttons are currently pressed) && also how to send output (make the mouse click at a specific position in another program). If you could also add comments on what different things do and why you use them would be terrific :D
Cheers! //Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a very good solution but bad as i am (didnt understand how to use the other ones that were suggested) i chose the siple way out... i used `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;` after getting the xna framework reference, then i simply went ahead and did `keyboardstate currentkeyboard = keyboard.getstate` :) same with mouse

Answer (score 0):

.NET only has .NET controls (forms, buttons,etc) based mouse/keyboard hooking built in, so to programmatically respond to those events outside your .NET controls you need a global event hook that can intercept mouse and keyboard activity from anywhere in windows.

HowTo use one keyboard/mouse hook dll to perform the functionality you are requesting (the ability to respond programmatically to mouse/keyboard events globally):

Download "Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll" from: [global mouse/keyboard kooks in c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Place this dll in C:\Windows\System32

In your project, include a reference (from VS, add...reference and browse to the dll)

In your project code, add "using Gma.UserActivityMonitor;"

In your code, declare these event consumers:

```
HookManager.MouseMove += HookManager_MouseMove;
HookManager.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(HookManager_KeyPress);
```

Here are some method stubs that can be raised when the mouse/keyboard events occur:

```
private void HookManager_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
}
private void HookManager_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
}
```

Hope this helps, this is how I did it when I needed to consume global mouse and keyboard events in my code.